# Test to see if a DFA accepts strings of a given language

Tags: computer-science

The full question is:

"One is thinking how to test if a DFA accepts all the strings of a given regular language. Suppose the language given by the regular expression (0+11)*1 wich represents the language over the alphabet E={0,1} with an odd number of 1’s, always finishing with 1, and with the other possible 1’s in groups of even length. A possible DFA is the one presented below:

[image]

Describe how to test if the DFA accepts all the strings of the language."

Even though I'm being told that the DFA is correct, I can also see it is. I was thinking that given a DFA one could use state elimination or path construction to get a RE. Or we could start with a RE, get a e-NFA, then DFA and simplify it. So, starting with one of them we could just use conversion methods to get the other one, is what I'm thinking.

But the way the question is phrased makes me think that there is somekind of other systematic method to test the DFA (with pen and paper, not putting it through a program).

So my question is, am I missing something by assuming that conversion methods are enough? I suppose that one problem could be not getting exactly the same expression or DFA and so it might be hard to see the equivalency.